# How to sort the collection on custom condition in laravel 5.7?

Tags: php, laravel, sorting, laravel-5.7, laravel-collection

I have an api ready that returns the following json response.

Response:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "conversation": [{
            "id": 37,
            "type": "1",
            "name": "Sonali",
            "created_at": "2019-02-18 13:26:10",
            "updated_at": "2019-02-18 20:32:54",
            "unread_count": 2,
            "chat": {
                "id": 357,
                "conversation_id": "23",
                "type": "text",
                "sender_id": "37",
                "receiver_id": "39",
                "data": "{\"text\":\"hello....\"}",
                "delivered_at": "2019-02-20 13:25:27",
                "seen_at": null,
                "created_at": "2019-02-20 13:25:10",
                "updated_at": "2019-02-20 13:25:27",
                "sender_name": "Sonali"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 38,
            "type": "1",
            "name": "Raviraj",
            "created_at": "2019-02-18 20:23:55",
            "updated_at": "2019-02-18 20:32:47",
            "unread_count": 0,
            "chat": {
                "id": 354,
                "conversation_id": "22",
                "type": "text",
                "sender_id": "39",
                "receiver_id": "38",
                "data": "{\"text\":\"hey....\"}",
                "delivered_at": null,
                "seen_at": null,
                "created_at": "2019-02-20 13:24:35",
                "updated_at": "2019-02-20 13:24:35",
                "sender_name": "Nitesh Kesarkar"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 27,
            "type": "1",
            "name": "Rakesh",
            "created_at": "2019-02-01 10:48:19",
            "updated_at": "2019-02-07 11:35:10",
            "unread_count": 1,
            "chat": {
                "id": 358,
                "conversation_id": "21",
                "type": "text",
                "sender_id": "27",
                "receiver_id": "39",
                "data": "{\"text\":\"hello\"}",
                "delivered_at": "2019-02-20 13:25:27",
                "seen_at": null,
                "created_at": "2019-02-20 13:25:24",
                "updated_at": "2019-02-20 13:25:27",
                "sender_name": "Rakesh Patil"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This response consists of list of users and their associated last chat message for currently logged in user. I want to sort this collection according to the latest message first. How can I do that?

Sorting should be based on the `chat.created_at` field.

Expected Result:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "conversation": [
        {
            "id": 27,
            "type": "1",
            "name": "Rakesh",
            "created_at": "2019-02-01 10:48:19",
            "updated_at": "2019-02-07 11:35:10",
            "unread_count": 1,
            "chat": {
                "id": 358,
                "conversation_id": "21",
                "type": "text",
                "sender_id": "27",
                "receiver_id": "39",
                "data": "{\"text\":\"hello\"}",
                "delivered_at": "2019-02-20 13:25:27",
                "seen_at": null,
                "created_at": "2019-02-20 13:25:24",
                "updated_at": "2019-02-20 13:25:27",
                "sender_name": "Rakesh Patil"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 37,
            "type": "1",
            "name": "Sonali",
            "created_at": "2019-02-18 13:26:10",
            "updated_at": "2019-02-18 20:32:54",
            "unread_count": 2,
            "chat": {
                "id": 357,
                "conversation_id": "23",
                "type": "text",
                "sender_id": "37",
                "receiver_id": "39",
                "data": "{\"text\":\"hello....\"}",
                "delivered_at": "2019-02-20 13:25:27",
                "seen_at": null,
                "created_at": "2019-02-20 13:25:10",
                "updated_at": "2019-02-20 13:25:27",
                "sender_name": "Sonali"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 38,
            "type": "1",
            "name": "Raviraj",
            "created_at": "2019-02-18 20:23:55",
            "updated_at": "2019-02-18 20:32:47",
            "unread_count": 0,
            "chat": {
                "id": 354,
                "conversation_id": "22",
                "type": "text",
                "sender_id": "39",
                "receiver_id": "38",
                "data": "{\"text\":\"hey....\"}",
                "delivered_at": null,
                "seen_at": null,
                "created_at": "2019-02-20 13:24:35",
                "updated_at": "2019-02-20 13:24:35",
                "sender_name": "Nitesh Kesarkar"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

***UPDATE*** :
Adding these lines worked as expected. Thanks @JCode

```
        $sorted = $chats->sortByDesc('chat.created_at');
        $chats = $sorted->values()->all();
```

Comment: What does this saying : DB::table('chart')->orderBy('user_registered', 'desc')->get()->toArray() ?

Comment: @ViperTecPro - 

 `$sorted = $chats->sortByDesc('chat.created_at');`
`$chats = $sorted->values()->all();`

This is what I did as per answer..

Comment: Does that resolved your issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the [`sortBy()` method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-sortby).

This will of course work if your JSON output can be turned into a collection via `collect()`—in a perfect scenario, your chat messages would be a model in Laravel.